# React Router, not found for dynamic page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

the "not found" page does not work for dynamic routes. It just throws a blank page.

app.tsx

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/recipe/:recipeid" element={<Detail />}>
          <Route path="comments" element={<DetailComments />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/addRecipe" element={<AddRecipe />} />
        <Route path="/Profile" element={<Profile />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
      {notificationIsShown && <Notification />}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code you've shared and can't reproduce the issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-not-found-for-dynamic-page-4npnlj Are there any errors? What are the steps to reproduce any issues? Could to create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: "The problem is when the `"/recipe/1"` exist it shows the page. When I write `"/recipe/25"` which does not exist it shows blank page instead "not found". - This isn't an issue with route matching at all. The `Detail` component needs to check the `id` param and determine if it is valid. Can you share the `Detail` component in your question?